# Android : query with date

Tags: android, date, select

I must to do a query but I have a problem with date becase the structure is 27/08/2011 this is the code :

```
dt="27/08/2011";
db.query(TABLE,null,mydata + "=" + dt,null,null,null,null);
```

the problem is that the cursor is always 0. I think that is the data structure because if I query other it work fine

Answer (score 2):

Your date isn't quoted so SQLite will interpret `27/08/2011` as a mathematical expression and replace it with `0` (the integer value of 27 divided by 8 divided by 2011). You could quote it yourself:

```
db.query(TABLE, null, mydata + "=" + "'" + dt + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Or better, [use a placeholder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
db.query(TABLE, null, mydata + "= ?", new String[] { dt }, null, null, null);
```

Switching to an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format would also be a good idea to avoid possible locale-based ambiguity in the date:

```
String dt = "2011/08/27";
Cursor c  = db.query(TABLE, null, mydata + "= ?", new String[] { dt }, null, null, null);
```

Comment: THanks for your answer. And with your method if I want select mydata and myid how is the code ?

Comment: @Mimmo: `mydata` is a column name rather than a String variable? If yes then `db.query(TABLE, new String[] { "mydate", "myid" }, "mydata = ?", ...`

Comment: This is right ??

    String dt = "2011/08/27";
    String n = "ciao"; 
    Cursor c  = db.query(TABLE, null, mydata + "= ? && " + myid + "=?", new String[] { dt,n }, null, null,null);

Comment: I want to do this : SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE mydata='dt' && myid='n' how can I do this ??

Comment: @Mimmo: I think you're looking for `db.query(TABLE, null, "mydata = ? AND myid = ?", new String[] { dt, n }, ...` where `n` is a String.